# Git pull and merge?

Tags: git

I Committed the code then before pushing it i run hard reset command so all my code deleted

After this i am trying to recover my commitetd code with the help of

```
git reflog
git reset <id_of_commit_to_which_you_want_restore>
```

But look like i again made some mistake,Now in history i am able to see my committed  file,please have a look attached image

[image]

Now i am trying to `pull` but its not working

```
$ git pull
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.
```

Then i tried `mergetool` that saying no file to merge

```
$ git mergetool
No files need merging
```

When i am trying to `git push` from attached image its saying pull first.

Now totally confused ,can someone please help me regarding this?

**Note-** Some other developer already committed some file in same project.

Comment: have you tried git push -f and then pull it?

Comment: ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (non-fast forward)

Comment: Try `git merge --abort` first.

Comment: Ok push after that?

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard  <commit>` should fix your **local** branch.

`git pull --rebase` should bring the change the other dev did and put yours on top of it.

Now you should be able to push.

**Do not, never, `git push --force` in shared repositories**

Comment: Thanks after running above two commands ,my committed code not back.Only i got all the latest changes . When i commit the code at that time i did hard reset wrongly.

Comment: If you have the sha of your commit, you can `git cherry-pick <your-commit>`

Comment: I resolved the conflict and commit again,now its saying,[remote rejected]   HEAD -> refs/for/master ([1def8ef] missing Change-Id in commit message footer)